# Why is ValidForm ignoring my validation expression?

Tags: javascript, php, regex, validform

The code below properly prevents the form from being submitted if anything between 1-11 characters is entered into the form field.

However, once 12-characters of any type are entered, the form field passes validation.

```
  $objGroup->addField('phone', 'Location Phone', VFORM_CUSTOM,
    array(
      'required' => false,
      'validation' => '/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/',
      'minLength' => 12,
      'maxLength' => 12
    ),
    array(
      'type' => 'Location Phone not entered correctly',
      'minLength' => 'Location Phone must be entered like ###-###-####'
    ),
    array(
      'hint' => '###-###-####',
      'tip' => 'Enter your phone number.',
      'default' => $GLOBALS['phone']
    )
  );
```

I need it to only permit a value string of 999-999-9999 whenever something is entered into the form field. What is incorrect with my code?

**Form Field entry with 11-characters (observe the error message in red) form cannot be submitted:**

[image]

**Form Field entry with 12-characters whereby the very last character is not numeric (observe *no error message* in red) form can be submitted:**

[image]

**Except from VFB Documentation**

```
#### Custom field types
* `VFORM_CUSTOM`
    This generates a text input field with a custom validation regular expression 

* `VFORM_CUSTOM_TEXT`
    This generates a textarea input field with a custom validation regular expression

##### Example - Validating a social security number
    $objSocialSecurity = $objForm->addField(
        "socialsecurity", 
        "Your social security number",
        VFORM_CUSTOM,
        array( 
            "validation" => "/^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/"
        ),
        array(
            "type" => "Invalid Social Security number"
        )
    );
```

**My Trial & Error Tests:**

1. copied and pasted the sample validation snippet from the documentation I found, verbatim. It did not make it work. My suspicion is there is some sort of disconnect between `"validation"` and `"type"`.
2. changed my use of single-quotes to double-quotes as shown in the documentation. It did not make it work.
3. re-ordered the position of `"validation"` and `"type"` within their respective array()s. It did not make it work.
4. changed `"type"` to `"validation"`. It did not make it work.
5. removed use of minLength and maxLength to see if there is a conflict. It did not make it work.
6. made the field required to see if the validation only works if form field is required. It did not make it work.
7. I've exhausted my t&e tests...

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the RegEx. Is the user input actually 12 characters long and in the proper format with no extra whitespace or anything funky?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this @tenub. I appended to my OQ to show you the behavior with certain entries.

Comment: Are you getting any errors / warnings in your PHP log?

Comment: No, this validation takes place client-side @JustinWood

Comment: In that case, are you getting any errors / warnings in your JavaScript console?

Comment: `'minLength' => 'Location Phone must be entered like ###-###-####'` -- here you have specified only a error message for `minLength` validation, haven't you?

Comment: No errors. Just re-ran test and checked the error console and nothing was reported @JustinWood.

Comment: There are 2 concurrent error checks taking place. The first is the one you picked up on @zerkms and the second is `'validation' => '/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/'` with `'type' => 'Location Phone not entered correctly'`

Comment: @vfbStudent: yes, and you have only specified the error message text for `minLength`. I have no idea what library you're using but how is it supposed to know that regexp validation error text message is in the `minLength` key?

Comment: The library comes from an OS called [ValidForm Builder](http://validformbuilder.org). I am following any documentation I can find on the tool.

Comment: I just posted an excerpt that I found in the VFB documentation @zerkms. I am trying to replicate their validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `^` and `$` chars from your regex:

`/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/`

With a minLength and maxLength of 12, `^` and `$` become superfluous, and can often cause validation problems of their own accord.

Comment: I did not answer the question, I have only edited it!

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. I got a little too carried away that it got solved and I looked at the wrong contributor. Thank you @user3320441 !!